# Conflict with using Master Model comprised of two models in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm creating a login screen for my MVC3 website. Obviously, the user logs in from this page but if they have forgotten their password they can click a link then Javascript hides the LogOn  and then a forgotten  appears where they can enter their email address. So I have a LogOnModel which requires the username and password fields to have a value. The ForgotModel requires that the emailAddress field have a value. Then on the page I use a LogOnMaster model that consists of both of these.

```
public class LogOnMasterModel : MasterViewModel
{
    public LogOnModel LoginViewModel { get; set; }
    public ForgettenModel ForgottenViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is when I click the submit button for LogOn, it wants the email address field to have a value. How can I make it only validate the LoginViewModel on the log in submit button and only validate the ForgottenModel when the forgotten submit button is clicked.

I can share code if need be.

I am open to completely different solutions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few methods you can use. The first would involve employing a custom validator that determines if the username/password fields are populated then the email address is not necessary. The second method you might try, since everything is apparently run with JavaScript, is to populate the email address field with some default ignored value (invalid@emailaddress.org or something) that is reset to empty when the Forgot Password link is clicked.